# How can i make a button onclick action open in a new window?

Tags: html

Im trying to create a button that links to a PDF file open in a new window.
Tried the _blank method but that didn't work.

```
<button onClick="parent.location='files/sample.pdf'" class="send" >Curriculum vitae</button>
</form>
```

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wgOFt.png)

Comment: Using a button? Why not an anchor tag? `target='_blank'` only works with an anchor tag.

Comment: Because i use multiple buttons, and i try to keep the styling the same

Comment: Yes, what I meant is... `target` is only an attribute on an anchor tag. You said you've tried target, so I was a little surprised seeing a button ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use an anchor tag and style it

```
<a class="btn btn-success" href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">Google</a>
```

Or you can change your button to

```
<button title="button title" class="action primary tocart" onclick=" window.open('http://www.google.com', '_blank'); return false;">Google</button>
```

Comment: Glad to help :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
<button type="button" onclick="window.open('http://www.website.com/page')"> button</button>
```